# How to communicate with Plotter Device

Tags: protocols, iot

Is there any open protocol so the already existing applications like AutoCAD or illustrator could communicate with a custom made plotter?

Comment: i dont know if i set it right. I need to build a custom plotter but use the already existing applications like AutoCAD, Illustrator to print to my custom plotter device

Comment: Like [HPGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HPGL) you mean ?